# elementary OS installer crashes

Tags: system-installation, boot, dual-boot, uefi

I'm running a Lenovo Yoga 720-15IKB. Trying to dual boot elementary OS with Windows10. At pretty near the end of the installation process when everything is being installed, it just crashes. It gives me a message that the setup quit unexpectedly and that I can send a message about it (sorry it's in Finnish and can't translate it 100% accurately).

It doesn't have any specs on the issue or what's causing it, the message window is just empty apart from telling that I can file a report about it.

When I click "close" it tries to collect problem information but then says "This is not an official elementary package. Please remove any third party package and try again."

However, when I reboot my computer, I get the grub menu and I could boot elementary succesfully from there. I'm just worried that it might be corrupt or something so I would rather fix the installation issue...

I've installed Ubuntu succesfully a couple times, but Elementary OS seems to give me a headache right now. :/

System is running in UEFI, Secure Boot is disabled as well as Fast Boot.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a bug with running the installer in Finnish. What I've done with elementary installations is that I've run the installer in English and afterwards changed the language to Finnish from the system settings. This way it's possible to bypass this error.

If you later notice some applications like LibreOffice not using the correct language, go back to the language settings and see if it prompts you to "complete installing the language support". For whatever reason this extra step is sometimes needed after installing applications.

Comment: Cheers! Changed the language to english for the installer and it installed succesfully. Thanks!